# How configure Spring Boot to show a custom @Endpoint in the base path '/actuator' but alphabetically?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In Spring Boot 2.4.1. For a custom `@Endpoint` I have the following:

```
@Component
@Endpoint(id="springhost")
class SpringHostEndpoint {

    @ReadOperation()
    HostInfo report() {
        ...
    }
}
```

It works fine, the custom `@Endpoint` appears under the `.../actuator` base path how `/springhost` as follows:

[image]

From above it is the second link or item.

The situation is that it is not located in the right place such as all the rest of endpoints, it according alphabetically

How configure Spring Boot to accomplish that automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot does not sort the links returned by the `/actuator` endpoint. While in such cases it is preferable that sorting is done on the client side, I've raised [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24845) to see if this is something we want to consider doing in a future release.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wrote some thoughts in GitHub. BTW, even if I don't add my custom endpoint, for all the set of SB's endpoints, only the first par or the half of the set of endpoints appears sorted, the rest unsorted